# link detection?

Tags: php

I asked a question yesterday about a problem that Im having with a program that Im trying to build [having problems passing array values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331409/having-problems-passing-array-values) .

the problem that I am having is that I have an array named $images() that for some bizarre reason wont accept values, however last night as  was playing around with the program something very bizarre occurred.

one of the links actually worked, even though the array was still somehow empty? this has led me to wonder if the pages somehow have a way of detecting if the links are being processed and somehow disable link downloading perhaps?

obviously I cant confirm this, and is nothing more than a conspiracy at this point but is this even possible? thanks for your help guys!

Comment: let me understand, you want to parse HTML code?

Comment: basically the process goes as: get a response from twitter, sort through the tweets for tweets containing url's to images, extract those url's, and process them to find the largest image on those pages and output them, I can get each component to work fine on its own, however once I put it all together it collapses at the images(); array no matter what I try

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The question isn't very explicit, but, i think you need a PHP HTML Parser!

**"A HTML DOM parser written in PHP5+ let you manipulate HTML in a very easy way!"**
Check out this site: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

If you use this class, it will be super easy to you parse and grab info from the Received HTML DOM.

**PS:** this will reduce extremly your code!

**Tip:** Use `var_export($varname);exit();` line by line to discover where is the problem on your code!

Comment: thank you very much for your help and advice! this will certainly be the next thing I attempt if im still unsuccessful in getting the program to work, constructive help no matter what the outcome is always tremendous, however I cannot understand the purpose of people who give people like me who are trying to learn programming a difficult time, these sorts of people should be banned!